# Beaglebone Black with Adafruit

Tags: beaglebone-black

I tried out the the BBB with the Adafruit python library.

I was connecting a Voltmeter to the right Pin and run the following program

```
 import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
 import time
 pin = "P8_10"

 GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)

 for x in range(0,5):
     print("High")
     GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.HIGH)
     time.sleep(1)
     print("Low")
     GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.LOW)
     time.sleep(1)

 GPIO.cleanup()
```

Unfortunalty it was always on high, I did try a 1kOhm pulldown resistor to the ground. Still the same always high.

I did try the it the other way using this code:

```
 import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
 import time
 pin = "P8_10"

 print("Setup " + pin)


 GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN)
    for x in range(0,5):
            if GPIO.input(pin):
                    print("High")
            else:
                    print("Low")
            time.sleep(0.5)

 print("end")
 GPIO.cleanup()
```

Connecting it over a 1kOhm resistor to ground. I did still stay High all the time.

The OS on my BBB is Ubuntu. Any suggestions what could be wrong with the setup?

Comment: Just to be sure, the pin you are checking is 5 down, 1 over, correct? Also, are you running python as `python your_script.py`, or as `sudo python your_script.py`

Comment: @Passerby I did run it in as a normal user, I'll try to run it as root tonight. I did use the most right pin 5 from the top if you count the first as one. I also tried all the surrounding ones to be sure and also different other pins (and also altering the pin var of course)

Comment: I suppose sudo didn't work?

Comment: @Passerby, Yes and Yes - I didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Adafruit Learn page for the library](http://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-io-python-library-on-beaglebone-black/installation-on-ubuntu)

> The majority of this library will need to be run as sudo in Ubuntu.

[this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926979/beaglebone-black-adafruit-io-python-library-gpio-user-permissions), and the [Github Bug closure](https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python/issues/36) as it is by design required to be run as sudo or root, **it should be an issue of not running the script as sudo**.

Comment: **Anything else, would be off topic for the EE stackexchange btw. It's essentially a linux/software question**

Comment: I tried sudo with no success unfortunatly...